# If all flesh will be resurrected, will dinosaurs be resurrected?

Tags: faith

The scriptures indicate that all flesh will be resurrected and that God will reverse the curse of sin which is death. Will dinosaurs be resurrected and will they be present on the New Earth along with resurrected mankind?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you cited specific verses for your opening statement that ALL flesh will be resurrected. I've never heard of resurrection ever being extended to animals.

Comment: Better question for this site is what does all flesh refer to in Luke 3:6

Answer (score 6):

Luke 3:6 does in fact say:

“And all flesh shall see the salvation of God” (KJV). (και οψεται πασα σαρξ το σωτηριον του θεου).

And then 1 Cor. 15:39 says:

“All flesh is not the same flesh: but there is one kind of flesh of men, another flesh of beasts, another of fishes, and another of birds”. (ου πασα σαρξ η αυτη σαρξ αλλα αλλη μεν ανθρωπων αλλη δε σαρξ κτηνων αλλη δε σαρξ πτηνων αλλη δε ιχθυων).

So it is probably a legitimate exegetical position to say that “all flesh” (men, beasts, fishes, birds…and why not dinosaurs?) “shall see the salvation of God”.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: It's a crap question, but not a bad answer. I gave you an upvote to neutralize whoever downvoted.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter (I actually upvoted), but maybe they wanted an answer specifically about resurrection rather than "seeing the salvation of God."

Comment: @fdb I would modify Daи's comment to say "A Good Answer To A Bad Question". Those Midwesterner's tend to speak in negative terms-if you're looking for affirmation from them, buy a dog. ;>)